# Out of Range error for sys.argv with Workbook.caller()

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

This issue is specific to *xlwings*. I'm having issues with `wb = Workbook.caller()`. Which results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "WeatherDataAPI.py", line 89, in <module>
    wb = Workbook.caller()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 234, in caller
    xl_app, xl_workbook = xlplatform.get_open_workbook(fullname, hwnd=sys.argv[4])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It looks like there was a similar issue in a [previous release](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/235) of xlwings?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Have you upgraded as suggested in the linked bugreport?

Comment: I did, yes. I have xlwings-0.6.2 installed.

Comment: You need to make sure that you have the same version in the VBA module. That's currently still a manual check to do.